# Area of a triangle - straight lines

Tags: integration, geometry, graphing-functions, analytic-geometry

Question:
What is the area of the triangle formed by the line $x + y = 3$ and angle bisectors of the pair of straight lines $x^2 - y^2 + 2y = 1$.

Well I really have no idea how to even start the question. Please help me by pointing me in the right direction! I tried to find the two equations from the pair of straight line equation given, but couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2 - y^2 + 2y = 1\iff x^2 = y^2 -2y+1 = (y-1)^2 \iff y-1 = \pm x \iff y = 1\pm x$$

Thus the two intersecting lines are given by $y = 1+x$ and $y = 1-x$. The point of intersection is given by $(0, 1)$.  One bisector is the y-axis: the line $x=0$. The other bisector is given by $y = 1$.

[image]

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you!!! I really missed that.

Comment: Wait though, How could the other line form a triangle with the angle bisectors?

Comment: The two angle bisectors intersect at a right angle, and the line $y = 3-x$ intersects those lines, with the segment between the points of intersection between it and each of the bisectors serving as the hypotenuse.

Comment: I see that now. One of the angle bisectors is the y-axis while the other is y = 1. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that was part of my answer ;-)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Missed that part. Yeah got the answer lol